# Batch - edit specified line in text file

Tags: batch-file, replace, text-files, edit

For example, line number 2 reads: "0" (without quotes). I want to change that 0 to a 1, without changing anything else in the text file.

I know what line the values will be on, so all i need to know is how to change that value to another value that I specify. I also will have to to the same with strings, not just numbers.

Example:

From:

```
4.7
0
check
0
1
0
0
```

To:

```
4.7
1
check
0
1
0
0
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
SET "file=file"
SET /a Line#ToSearch=2
SET "Replacement=0"

(FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%a IN ('findstr /n "^" "%file%"') DO (
    SET "Line=%%b"
    IF %%a equ %Line#ToSearch% SET "Line=%Replacement%"
    SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
    ECHO(!Line!
    ENDLOCAL
))>"%file%.new"
TYPE "%file%.new"
```

Note: this doen't work properly for lines starting with colons `:`, this might be fixed if needed.

Comment: right, but is it not possible to edit the original text file, or is it necessary to create new one?

Comment: a `temp`  file is always needed, you can't write to the original file. But you can put the following code at the end: `MOVE "%file%.new" "%file%"`, this replaces the old file with the new one.