# Batch - edit single line in file

Tags: batch-file, replace, edit

I was searching for a batch script which edits a specific and known line in another batch-file. 
I found this solution ([Stackoverflow: Batch - edit specified line in text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18395013/batch-edit-specified-line-in-text-file)) and it was almost workiing properly. The only problem I had with the script from Endoro is that it deletes the colons at the start of a line which I don't want to edit. Is there a way to avoid this from happening?
Help would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL

:Input  
    set /p version=Please Enter Version: 


:Replacement
    SET "file=test.bat"
    SET /a Line#ToSearch=4
    SET "Replacement=set jversion = %Version%_x86"

(FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=: " %%a IN ('findstr /n "^" "%file%"') DO (
        SET "Line=%%b"
        IF %%a equ %Line#ToSearch% SET "Line=%Replacement%"
        SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
        ECHO(!Line!
        ENDLOCAL
    ))>"%file%.new"
TYPE "%file%.new"
MOVE "%file%.new" "%file%"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for /F` treats subsequent delimiters as one. `findstr /N` precedes every line with a line number and a colon. So for instance if the third line is `:abcd ef`, `for /F` receives `3::abcd ef`. After parsing the two tokens, you will get `3` and `abcd ef`. That is why leading colons disappear.

To overcome this, use sub-string replacement syntax; supposing variable `Line` contains the entire line including the line number prefix (string `3::abcd ef` from above), use `SET "Line=!Line:*:=!"` to remove everything up to and including the first colon (so the resulting string is `:abcd ef`).

To get the line number, use another `for /F` loop with `:` as delimiter, fetching the first token only.

Here is the fixed script:

```dos
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL

:Input
    set /p version=Please Enter Version: 


:Replacement
    SET "file=test.bat"
    SET /a Line#ToSearch=4
    SET "Replacement=set jversion = %Version%_x86"

(FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('findstr /n "^" "%file%"') DO (
        SET "Line=%%a"
        rem // Use a `for /F` loop to extract the line number:
        for /F "delims=:" %%N in ("%%a") do set "LNum=%%N"
        SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
        rem // Use sub-string replacement to split off
        rem // the preceding line number and one colon:
        SET "Line=!Line:*:=!"
        IF !LNum! equ %Line#ToSearch% SET "Line=%Replacement%"
        ECHO(!Line!
        ENDLOCAL
    ))>"%file%.new"
TYPE "%file%.new"
MOVE "%file%.new" "%file%"
```

Comment: Hello aschipfl, thanks for the quick help.
I testet your adaptation and I noticed that script itself won't change anything now (not even in line 4 as supposed). I won't get any error messages though and the script is creating the ".new" file (i deleted the last line).

Comment: Thank you very much. The script is working like a charm now :) !